# How to use windows phone toolkit in windows phone 8.1 universal app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, wptoolkit

I have added windows phone toolkit using nuget package in windows 8.1 universal app project. it is added successfully, but I can't see reference assemblies in the project and neither i can add reference in page xaml to use toolkit controls. How can use windows toolkit in universal windows phone 8.1 app?

Comment: Which components do you wish to use, and 
have you checked to see if the components you wish to use, are not already available in the Windows Runtime framework?

Comment: Thanks Clause, I want to use l want to use listpicker control from toolkit.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen-MSFT is there any alternate control for listpicker in default controls in windows runtime framework?

Comment: Combo box is good alternative.

Comment: ListPickerFlyout is there for list picker control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Windows Phone Toolkit is currently (26th of April, 2014) only supporting Silverlight 8.0 / 8.1 applications.

If you wish to re-use components, you would need to [download the source from CodePlex](http://phone.codeplex.com/) and port the individual components to a Windows Runtime library project. However, this might require a (very) large portion of work.

Comment: Any idea when this could be made available for 8.1 universal apps?

Comment: I also need the same can you suggest me another approaches!!