# system tray in xaml windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro

how can i hide this icons,

?

problem is i always have same color background even if theme is black or light and it is not looking good, i know it is possible to hide it. in xaml but i dont know the best way !

i tried this one ! but not working :(

```
<Page 
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:PuzzleTalk"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
Shell:SystemTray.IsVisiable="False" 
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're applying a Silverlight solution to a non Silverlight project.

Answer (score 5):

There's a typo in your code - you have `Shell:SystemTray.IsVisiable="False"` try `Shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"` instead...

Comment: i updated my question, as per your suggestion :( still same problem

Answer (score 4):

Based off your XAML tags, you're trying to do this with `Windows Phone 8.1 runtime`

`<Page>` was the dead give away.

The `shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"` is only for`Windows Phone 8 Silverlight` and `Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight`

---

Code to hide Status Bar

```C#
StatusBar statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();

// Hide the status bar
await statusBar.HideAsync();

//Show the status bar
await statusBar.ShowAsync();
```

Taken from [Hide Status bar in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009501/hide-status-bar-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-apps)

Comment: so i m not able to use the windows phone toolkit controls? if i am not using windows phone8.1 sliverlight?

Comment: for now, i am not really sure, which project i need to choose, i am guy who know windows phone 8 controls very much!

Comment: @patel Windows Phone Toolkit is only supported in Silverlight 8.0/8.1 atm : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308632/how-to-use-windows-phone-toolkit-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app

Comment: @patel if you want a screenshot on how to create a WP Silverlight app : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090201/target-windows-phone-8-project-on-vs2013/25090314#25090314

Comment: alright, i understood, but the question is , which is better for future?

Comment: If you're more familiar with classic Windows Phone development, eg 7 and 8, then Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight apps will be most familiar to you. If you are starting out, or looking to the future, it's probably better to start with "universal" apps, ie Windows Phone 8.1 runtime - it will make your apps easier to convert for the Windows 8 store and Windows 10 is likely to take that direction even further.